# How to get the correct number corresponding to the line in pseudocode?

Tags: pseudocode, algpseudocode

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Random Vector Generation}
\begin{algorithmic}
\State Generate $\mathit{n}$ random variables $\mathit{U_{1},...,U_{n}}$ as iid variables from $\mathit{U(0,1)}$ \newline
\State Set $X_{1} = 1- X_{n},...,X_{n} = 1- 2U_{n}$ and $\mathit{R = \sum_{i=1}^n X_{i}^2}$ \newline
\State if $\mathit{R \leq 1}$, accept $\mathit{\textbf{X} = (X_{1},....X_{n})^T}$ as the desired vector; otherwise go to step 1.
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

[image]

Comment: As always on this site: you are much more likely to get help if you provide a full but minimal example that others can just copy and test. Here there are no document class or preamble.

Comment: `\begin{algorithmic}[1]` should work, see the examples in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you got that picture, because the call

```
\begin{algorithmic}
```

is equivalent to

```
\begin{algorithmic}[0]
```

meaning “no line numbers”. You want

```
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
```

which means “number every line”.

Here's working code, with a better trick instead of `\newline` in order to space out the lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Random Vector Generation}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\setlength{\itemsep}{1ex}
\State Generate $n$ random variables $U_{1},\dots,U_{n}$ as iid variables from
       $U(0,1)$
\State Set $X_{1} = 1- 2U_{1},\dots,X_{n} = 1- 2U_{n}$ and $R = \sum_{i=1}^n X_{i}^2$
\State if $R \leq 1$, accept $\mathbf{X} = (X_{1},\dots,X_{n})^T$ as the desired vector;
       otherwise go to step~1.
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Note that I removed all `\mathit` declarations and transformed `...` into `\dots`. I also fixed `X_{1}=1-2U_{1}`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @egreg, I am just learning to use LaTeX and this is really helpful.